# Crystal report - Null fields not shown

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I have, problem with and empty field as they disappear from reports.
I'm able to see only fields with data in them.

```
if isnull ({orddet_user.orddetlookup2}) 
then "No Reason" 
else {orddetlookup2.descr}
```

It returns on report {orddetlookup2.descr} but all blank fields doesn't show up,

Maybe someone has faced this before.
I'm using crystal 2008

Comment: Should be `if isnull({orddetlookup2.descr})...` ??

Comment: My bad with an empty space, But nope that didn't help

Comment: The whitespace after `isnull` shouldn't matter. Is it possible that this field contains the empty string? If so, that would make the field appear empty and not get caught by the `isnull()` check

Comment: Hmm. I've tried to add column to report without formulas, and it made me wonder. whenewer field is empty from orddet_user.orddetlookup2  it disappears from report together with other linked records... So in report im only able to see record if in this field i have one of letters ( a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) which describes reason, but if it's not set then nothing.

Comment: May be there is filtering that is making it disappear from report when field is null

Comment: It happens only with this specific table. If i have emtpy fields in other table it simply doesn't show specific field. but with this one disappears everything.

Comment: Hi, Thanks guys for trying to help. Issue was with Links.